# display an image from an array of images to a modal using react hooks

Tags: reactjs

I have a component that displays locally stored images from a json file using the map method. What I would like to do is when I click on any of the images I would like the image to be displayed in a modal. When I tried to pass the id of the image as a prop to the modal, and try to console.log it its displaying all the available ids but not the id of the clicked image.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";

import { Card, Modal } from "react-bootstrap";

import { data } from "../assets/images/stuff";
import "../assets/css/aboutUs.css";

const StuffInfo = (props) => {
  return (
    <Modal {...props} aria-labelledby="contained-modal-title-vcenter" centered>
      <Modal.Body>
      
        <div className="col-sm-6 col-md-4 mb-3  stuff">
          <Card key={props.id}>
            <Card.Img src={data.src} />
            <p>{data.stuffName}</p>
            <span>{data.title}</span>
          </Card>
        </div>
      </Modal.Body>
    </Modal>
  );
};

function AboutUs() {
  const [showModal, setShowModal] = useState(false);
  const [imge, setImge] = useState("");

  const handleClick = (id) => {
    console.log("Id is", id);

    setShowModal(true);
    setImge(data[id].src);
    console.log("image is", imge);
  };

  return (
    <div className="about-us">
      <h3>Lorem Ipsum</h3>
      <div className="info">
        <p>
          Sed ut perspiciatis, unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam eaque ipsa, quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt, explicabo
        </p>
        <h4>Lorem Ipsum </h4>
        <p>
         Sed ut perspiciatis, unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam eaque ipsa, quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt, explicabo
        </p>
      </div>
      <div className="our-services">
        <h4>Lorem Ipsum</h4>
        <div className="row">
          <div className="col-lg-4 col-md-6 train">
            <h5>Lorem Ipsum </h5>
            <div className="info-text">
              <i
                className="fa fa-graduation-cap"
                style={{ color: "#ff689b" }}
              ></i>
              <p>
             Sed ut perspiciatis, unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam eaque ipsa, quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt, explicabo
              </p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div className="col-lg-4 col-md-6 train">
            <h5>Lorem Ipsum </h5>
            <div className="info-text">
              <i
                className="fa fa-wrench"
                aria-hidden="true"
                style={{ color: "#e9bf06" }}
              ></i>
              <p>
              Sed ut perspiciatis, unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam eaque ipsa, quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt, explicabo
              </p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div className="col-lg-4 col-md-6 train">
            <h5>Lorem Ipsum </h5>
            <div className="info-text">
              <i
                className="fa fa-universal-access"
                style={{ color: "#3fcdc7" }}
              ></i>
              <p>
               Sed ut perspiciatis, unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam eaque ipsa, quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt, explicabo
              </p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <h5>Lorem Ipsum</h5>
      <div className="row">
        {data &&
          data.map((stuff, id) => (
            <div
              className="col-sm-6 col-md-4 mb-3  stuff"
              key={id}
              onClick={() => handleClick(id)}
            >
              <Card key={data.id}>
                <img src={stuff.src} id={id} />
                <p>{stuff.stuffName}</p>
                <span>{stuff.title}</span>
              </Card>
              <StuffInfo
                show={showModal}
                onHide={() => setShowModal(false)}
                id={data.id}
              />
            </div>
          ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default AboutUs;

StuffInfo.propTypes = {
  id: PropTypes.string,
  onHide: PropTypes.func,
};
```

This is the code that  I tried based on the suggetion.

```
 <div className="row">
        {data &&
          data.map((stuff, id) => (
            <div
              className="col-sm-6 col-md-4 mb-3  stuff"
              key={id}
              onClick={() => setImge(id)}
            >
              <Card key={data.id}>
                <img src={stuff.src} id={id} />
                <p>{stuff.stuffName}</p>
                <span>{stuff.title}</span>
              </Card>
            </div>
          ))}

        <StuffInfo
          show={imge > -1}
          onHide={() => setImge(-1)}
          id={imge}
          data={data}
        />
      </div>
    </div>

const StuffInfo = ({ data, id }) => {
  {
    console.log("DATA is", data[id].src, data[id].stuffName, data[id].title);
  }
  return (
    <Modal aria-labelledby="contained-modal-title-vcenter" centered>
      <Modal.Body>
        <div className="col-sm-6 col-md-4 mb-3  stuff">
          <Card key={id}>
            <Card.Img src={data[id].src} />
            <p>{data[id].stuffName}</p>
            <span>{data[id].title}</span>
          </Card>
        </div>
      </Modal.Body>
    </Modal>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You have `StuffInfo` for each data item, and they all share the same `showModal` flag, so when you flip it to true, they're all shown at the same time.
Instead of  `showModal` you can keep the id of the selected item in the state and check it against current id `show={data.id === selectedId}`, or better still move `StuffInfo` outside of the loop, if you have just one  `StuffInfo`  it'll look something like

```
          <StuffInfo
            show={selectedId > -1}
            onHide={() => setSelectedId(-1)}
            id={selectedId}
          />
```

Made you a working example https://codesandbox.io/s/react-bootstrap-playground-forked-wkzp5

Comment: Sorry for the late replay. I tried it the way you suggested but its still not workin

Comment: can you make a reproducible example of this?

Comment: With your example I can now pass all the data array of the id to the modal. But now I cant display the modal.

Comment: You are not using the `show` flag inside `StuffInfo` , I think you were passing it to Modal before, via `...props`